# C# CRC32 how to get 8 digit result

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, algorithm, crc

I have this requirement to get the CRC32 checksum of a file. I have tried [this](https://crc32c.machinezoo.com/#net) library and this class:

```
public sealed class Crc32 : HashAlgorithm
{
    public const UInt32 DefaultPolynomial = 0xedb88320u;
    public const UInt32 DefaultSeed = 0xffffffffu;

    static UInt32[] defaultTable;

    readonly UInt32 seed;
    readonly UInt32[] table;
    UInt32 hash;

    public Crc32()
        : this(DefaultPolynomial, DefaultSeed)
    {
    }

    public Crc32(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed)
    {
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Not supported on Big Endian processors");

        table = InitializeTable(polynomial);
        this.seed = hash = seed;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        hash = seed;
    }

    protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
    {
        hash = CalculateHash(table, hash, array, ibStart, cbSize);
    }

    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        var hashBuffer = UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(~hash);
        HashValue = hashBuffer;
        return hashBuffer;
    }

    public override int HashSize { get { return 32; } }

    public static UInt32 Compute(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Compute(DefaultSeed, buffer);
    }

    public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Compute(DefaultPolynomial, seed, buffer);
    }

    public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(polynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    static UInt32[] InitializeTable(UInt32 polynomial)
    {
        if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial && defaultTable != null)
            return defaultTable;

        var createTable = new UInt32[256];
        for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            var entry = (UInt32)i;
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                if ((entry & 1) == 1)
                    entry = (entry >> 1) ^ polynomial;
                else
                    entry >>= 1;
            createTable[i] = entry;
        }

        if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial)
            defaultTable = createTable;

        return createTable;
    }

    static UInt32 CalculateHash(UInt32[] table, UInt32 seed, IList<byte> buffer, int start, int size)
    {
        var hash = seed;
        for (var i = start; i < start + size; i++)
            hash = (hash >> 8) ^ table[buffer[i] ^ hash & 0xff];
        return hash;
    }

    static byte[] UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(UInt32 uint32)
    {
        var result = BitConverter.GetBytes(uint32);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I noticed that the results are different for the both of them. I am trying to load this file onto a server using an application called the Oracle WCC BatchLoader which also checks the checksum of the file. So far, both libraries have failed to be accepted by the BatchLoader due to the CRC. Is there a difference how they are calculated?

Comment: There are several flavors of CRC.  You'll have to figure out which one the Oracle WCC BatchLoader is using.

Comment: The person told me its crc32. However right now, both libraries im testing give different results.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  Three different CRC32 libraries can give three different results.  Unfortunately, [Google isn't much help here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Oracle+WCC+BatchLoader+%22CRC32%22).  You may have to contact Oracle.

Comment: See Sunshine : http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "the" CRC-32. I see about a dozen [here](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm), and I'm sure there are others, all of which give different answers. You need to find out the specifications for the CRC-32 used by the software you are trying to interface with.

You can look for that in the documentation of that software. Or you could provide a few example files that *are* accepted, and identify where the CRC is and what data the CRC is calculated on. Then we could see if it is one of the more common, documented CRC-32s.